# How to use binomial regression in Python? Or any other appropriate analysis for this data set

Tags: machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

How can I use binomial regression or any other appropriate analysis technique to find out how all of these factors affect the wins and losses of these teams?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each team we can know prob of winning. That becomes target variable. Once prob of win is know. You can calculate binomial distribution

It is regression problem, so I will
Go for linear regression or DecisionTreeRegression. Do remember to prevent overfitting.